# input text from file java

Tags: java, inputstream, file-io

I'm trying to get read in a file. I have this so far as my code

```
public static File readFileInfo(Scanner kb)throws FileNotFoundException
{String fileName;
System.out.print("enter file name: ");
fileName = kb.nextLine();    
file infile = new file(filename)
Scanner fin = new Scanner(inFile);
return fin
```

i get this error code

```
FileUtil.java:23: incompatible types
found   : java.util.Scanner
required: java.io.File
```

from here on i'm sort of lost any help would be awesome! thanks guys!

Comment: Java **is case-sensitive**, re-check your code and you'll see what is wrong

Comment: How would you feel if someone goes shopping and promises to bring back beer, but actually brings milk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring your casing (as this would not give the error you have posted, but is an error)

Your method has a return type of `File`. You are returning a `Scanner` object.

To fix this either

1. return the `File` instead of the `Scanner`

   ```
   return inFile;
   ```
2. Change the return type to Scanner

   ```
   public static Scanner readFileInfo(Scanner kb){//...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that case matters while working in a language such as Java.  The variable Foo is different from foo.  Go over your code again and your error will be pretty obvious.